# Using Data Validation with drop-down list

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Data Validation to create a drop down list in an audit sheet. My user will choose one of the text description values, which has a corresponding score of 1-5.

I am trying to sum the results of a column of these drop-down results, so am trying to extract the numerical value. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean that you have a column of descriptions (which have been picked by the user through a data validation) and each description carry a score. Now you want to get the sum of all the scores from that column?

Comment: Exactly right Jerry. The text descriptions are to help the user to define the score that will then be used for further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it'll be easiest I think if you have some sort of hidden column just after the column containing the descriptions and a reference table somewhere for the scores.

E.g.
Cell A2 contains 'Agree'.
Cell range Z1:AA5 contains the reference table:

```
Highly agree    5
Agree           4
No opinion      3
Disagree        2
Highly disagree 1
```

In the hidden cell B2, put the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, $Z$1:$AA$5, 2, 0), 0)
```

Ad fill this formula until the end of the table.

At the end, you can put a sum there:

```
=SUM($B$2:$B$30)
```

Assuming that the table ends at row 30 in the sheet.

---

Otherwise, if that's not possible, you can use an array function and 5 nested IFs, 1 for each description:

`=SUM((IF(A2:A30="Highly agree",5,IF(A2:A30="Agree",4,IF(A2:A30="No opinion",3,IF(A2:A30="Disagree",2,IF(A2:A30="Highly disagree",1,0)))))))`

This formula will be working correctly only when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> because it's an array formula.

---

Another option I think you might use is put the score together with the descriptions, e.g., make the descriptions like this:

```
5 Highly agree
4 Agree
3 No opinion
2 Disagree
1 Highly disagree
```

Then, you can use the other array formula:

```
=SUM(LEFT(A2:A30,1)*1)
```

Similarly, this formula will be working correctly only when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> because it's an array formula.

Comment: @IainFerguson You're welcome! It seems something is wrong though? Were you perhaps expecting something else?

Comment: Hi Jerry - No your help has solved my problem. I used =SUM(LEFT(A2:A30,1)*1) in a hidden column to generate numerical values and then sum the total - works a treat - thank you